# What's the proper order of stages in a CI build?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops

I've read some articles about CI/CD and find that a typical CI pipeline often includes Build, Test and Deploy. We also add Code Quality Scan stage to our pipeline. The question is that, what is the proper order of them? Should Test goes before Build or after? Is there any best practice?

Comment: It’s hard to test something you haven’t built yet.

Comment: The order is usually driven by dependencies. You need to compile to be able to test, and you don't deploy code that hasn't passed tests.

Answer (score 8):

## There is no proper order.

What is good for one repository is bad for another.

The proper order is the one that makes the most sense for your code base. This might mean:

- several pipelines
- keeping on testing even though the code is already known to be broken/or just discarding it the moment its known to be bad.
- a long chain of jobs, or many parallel jobs that synchronise for deployment.
- maybe the scan goes before the build, maybe they are side by side, maybe it comes after.

In general:

1. Respect Temporal dependencies (*you cannot deploy what has not been built*)
2. Optimise to quickly notify the developer of relevant feedback. (*the total time between the developer pushing the code in and the developer actually becoming aware of the feedback*).
3. Get buy in and the relevant checks/tests/verifications from each department that has to sign off the software being built. (*So that the least amount of manual verification is required*)

## Tests

In all but the smallest code base you will have several different forms of tests, and they will take more than a few minutes to execute.

- Units tests
- Module tests
- Integration Tests
- Deployment Tests
- End to End tests
- Performance and Load tests

Just to name a few, and they will require different test rigs.

It is usually best to break the tests up into smaller quicker to run test sets (even if that means running two or more sets of unit/module/integration/etc.. tests), and schedule them so that the tests most likely to fail, are run soonest.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the order of operations.  If test comes before you build the product, then your testing isn't against the changes introduced.  It also depends on if you are intending to employ simple CI/CD, full DevOps, or DevSecOps.  The only distinctions between them are the steps that need to happen, and the guarantees you must enforce.

Let's start with simple **CI/CD**:

- Build the code (nothing else happens)
- Run any instrumentation (like SonarQube to do static analysis and measure coverage)
- Run unit tests -- failed unit tests *should* fail the build
- Push deployed code to target environment
- Run any automated tests against the target environment (integration tests, Cucumber/Selenium, etc.)

With **DevOps**, you build on the above scenario and map branches in your code to environments.  As features are promoted from "develop" to "integration" and ultimately to "master" (production) then it is deployed to each of those environments.  The only difference is that the automated tests you already ran in the other environments don't get run in production since you don't want to mess with production data.

Finally, **DevSecOps** adds steps and additional build failure requirements.  The main difference between DevOps and DevSecOps is the automated security testing that gets added.  You can use a combination of scanning tools like SaltStack vulnerability management and automated penetration testing like Arachni.  Add to that any specific security testing you need for your application, all before you deploy the application.

With **DevSecOps**, you typically also set minimum coverage rules for your unit testing, build failure rules based on how serious the known problem is.  Category 1 problems present very serious risk to your project and may put you in a position for law suits or losing lots of money.  Category 2 problems are still serious, but can also be quarantined more easily.  Get enough of them and the build should fail.  Category 3 problems are relatively low risk, and may only cause embarrassment.  However, enough of them and the build should fail.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know what each step is doing. For e.g. in the case of a *test* step with code coverage, there are tools that instrument the code with dummy data, you definitely do not want such code to be released to production. So you test, clean and pack the application.

Deployment can be in a separate pipeline. Every branch commit is built and published somewhere with a version, then on the other pipeline, you can deploy to a given instance only the branch/version combination that you need.